# Mysql group by returns wrong result when using indexes

Tags: mysql, indexing, group-by

I have an issue in one of mySql query. Issue is not reproducible on any of our local machines. 
I have a simple query

```
SELECT ID 
FROM TABLE_NAME 
WHERE ID IN (15920,15921) 
GROUP BY ID
```

returns result –

```
ID
15920
```

Which is unexpected result since there is data for both the ids in database.

Using explain command returned the following result for this query

```
+----+-------------+------------+-------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+-----+------+---------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type  | possible_keys      | Key                | key_len | Ref | rows | Extra                                 |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+-----+------+---------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | TABLE_NAME | range | CUST_SID_SRUN_INDX | CUST_SID_SRUN_INDX |       4 |     |    1 | Using where; Using index for group-by |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+-----+------+---------------------------------------+
```

For this issue I have tried following solutions -

•   Forcing a derived table –

```
SELECT ID
FROM (SELECT ID 
      FROM TABLE_NAME 
      WHERE ID IN (15920,15921)) CUST 
GROUP BY ID
```

•   Using having clause instead of where clause

```
SELECT ID 
FROM TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY ID 
HAVING ID IN (15920,15921)
```

•   Ignoring the index used in this table –

```
SELECT ID 
FROM TABLE_NAME IGNORE INDEX (CUST_SID_SRUN_INDX)  
WHERE ID IN (15920,15921) 
GROUP BY ID
```

All the above queries return the expected result as follow  :-

```
ID
15920
15921
```

I am trying to analyze the unexpected behavior of group by clause when indexes are used. Please let me know if I could try something else. 
FYI…The UAT box where the issue occurs is a linux machine with Mysql 5.1.30. The difference that we see is the version of Mysql. We are using Mysql 5.1.52 on our machines.
The table which has this issue uses MyISAM databse engine.

Please let me know if any other input is required.

Comment: What is the data type of your `ID` column?  If it's a string type, the key-length of 4-bytes suggests that MySQL has only indexed (at most) the first four characters of the column's value and thus cannot differentiate between `15920` and `15921`.  Otherwise, I'd suggest attempting to [repair](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/repair-table.html) the index.

Comment: ID is int type with not null values. I tried taking a dump and restoring to a new database.When restored on the same machine the issue is still coming. But when I restored it on other machine it is working fine. Index definition for table is as follow :Table Non_unique Key_name Seq_in_index Column_name Collation Cardinality Sub_part Packed Null Index_type Comment
table_name 1 CUST_SID_SRUN_INDX 1 ID A 68    BTREE 
table_name 1 CUST_SID_SRUN_INDX 2 RUN A 428    BTREE

Comment: Are you doing this in a stored procedure by chance or just running the query in a vacuum?

Comment: No we are not using any stored procedure.We are simply executing this query on mysql console.

Comment: @Eggyal One more thing to mention we have tried rebuilding indexes also. The problem  is still there. The issue is coming only on one server, i expect there may pe some mySql configuration issue.

Comment: Please show output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE TABLE_NAME`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for your help .

There is a issue in MySql 5.1.30 with MyISAM partitions, after banging my head for several days I have resolved the issue by upgrading MySQL to 5.1.52 version or reorganizing the partitions .

For your reference see the following bugs reported on MySQL forum :

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=44821

Answer (score 0):

If your query results are wrong using indexes, it is possible that your table is corrupt for some reason. Try:

```
REPAIR TABLE table_name;
```

or try backup the data, destroy and re-create the table and repopulate the data into the table from your backup (that will also recreate the indexes)

Visit [MySQL Reference Manual - rebuilding tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/rebuilding-tables.html)